# Create/Read/Update/Delete to an XML file

Tags: coldfusion

Are there a set of commands used to perform CRUD on an XML file?
I'm envisioning a component (myData.cfc) that has a Save function (Insert/Update), a Delete function and a Read function.

Comment: "cfc"?  Please spell out words in English.  (I'm aware that it's a Cold Fusion term, not everyone is, however.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking about a way to use a XML file to store data? While you certainly can do that, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. You would have to be extremely careful to single thread the updates and you would not get good performance out of it. I mean it would probably work fine for a few hundred rows, but after that your going to suffer.

Can you elaborate on how you want to use the XML file? If you just mean settings, or a static set of data, I think it's fine. If you mean CRUD as in "N rows of data", you really want a database.